# F.write has returned 'io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable' and I don't know why

Tags: python

I am trying to write to a leaderboard text file and I can't tell why but it keeps giving me the error code 'io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable'. I am trying to write the \n to create a new line but it gives the error code, I tried it without that and it still gives the same error for f.write(writeToFile).

The relevant code is here:

```
   with open('leaderboard.txt') as f:
            stringScore = str(score)
            writeToFile = username + "#" + stringScore
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(writeToFile)
```

If you have any questions, as this is part of a bigger project I will try and get back to you but I'm not super active, thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: add permission to the file. eg.   with open('leaderboard.txt',**'w'**) as f:

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify in what mode you are opening a file. By default it opens in read-only mode do this instead:

```
   with open('leaderboard.txt',"w") as f:
            stringScore = str(score)
            writeToFile = username + "#" + stringScore
            f.write("\n")
            f.write(writeToFile)
```

Comment: I have already mentioned this in the comments. And this is not an explicit answer also.

Comment: It is good to post this as a comment instead of an answer. Anyway, you have missed bracket at the end `)`